# Help with looping arrays into existing divs

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, html

I'm trying to call three different arrays to existing divs, the end result should show four boxes with information dynamically filled from javascript.

However it doesn't work, and only shows the results from my `productDesc` array.

Here is my code:

```
var productNames = new Array(); 
productNames[0]="One";       
productNames[1]="Two";
productNames[2]="Three";
productNames[3]="Four";

var productImages = new Array(); 
productImages[0]= "Image 1 here";     
productImages[1]= "Image 2 here";     
productImages[2]= "Image 3 here";     
productImages[3]= "Image 4 here";     

var productDesc= new Array(); 
productDesc[0]= "This is product One";     
productDesc[1]= "This is product Two";     
productDesc[2]= "This is product Three";     
productDesc[3]= "This is product Four";   


function createItems() 
{   
  for (var i=0; i<productNames.length; i++) {

    document.getElementById("product" + i).innerHTML = productNames[i];
    document.getElementById("product" + i).innerHTML = productImages[i];
    document.getElementById("product" + i).innerHTML = productDesc[i];
  }
};
```

Here is the HTML

```
<body onload="createItems()">

    <div id="product">
        <span id="product0"></span>
        <br/>
        <a href="#">Buy</a>
    </div>

    <div id="product">
        <span id="product1"></span>
        <br/>
        <a href="#">Buy</a>
    </div>

    <div id="product">
        <span id="product2"></span>
        <br/>
        <a href="#">Buy</a>
    </div>

    <div id="product">
        <span id="product3"></span>
        <br/>
        <a href="#">Buy</a>
    </div>    

</body>
```

Comment: you have FOUR same IDs on your markup. each ID must be unique in the document.

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean

```
var productNames = new Array(); 
    productNames[0]="One";       
    productNames[1]="Two";
    productNames[2]="Three";
    productNames[3]="Four";

var productImages = new Array(); 
    productImages[0]= "Image 1 here";     
    productImages[1]= "Image 2 here";     
    productImages[2]= "Image 3 here";     
    productImages[3]= "Image 4 here";     

var productDesc= new Array(); 
    productDesc[0]= "This is product One";     
    productDesc[1]= "This is product Two";     
    productDesc[2]= "This is product Three";     
    productDesc[3]= "This is product Four";   

function createItems() {    
    for (var i=0; i<productNames.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("product" + i).innerHTML = productNames[i];
        document.getElementById("product" + i).innerHTML += productImages[i];
        document.getElementById("product" + i).innerHTML += productDesc[i];
    }
};
```